# What are the physical dimensions of the SSD used in the MacBook Air?

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

I need the dimensions of the "gum-stick" SSD (solid-state drive) used in 2011 MacBook Air models, preferably in cm or mm.

[image: Macbook Air SSD]

Comment: If you need them to be that precise, perhaps you need to disassemble your MacBook Air, remove the module, and measure it with calipers yourself.

Comment: See if there is any data at http://iFixit.com.

Comment: @WheatWilliams I'm not asking for extra precision, just for measures in [SI units](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_System_of_Units). iFixit only gives the thickness of the drive: 2.45 mm. I need the width/length, and I still don't have the pentalobe screwdriver to open my MBAs.

Comment: You could also check with Other World Computing at http://macsales.com. And either Other World or iFixit would be glad to sell you a pentalobe screwdriver. :-)

Comment: Can I be curious? Why do you need to know that? :)

Comment: @MartínMarconcini You can be curious... I might wand to fit a few of these into a different device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Techrepublic](http://www.techrepublic.com/photos/cracking-open-the-apple-macbook-air-2011-11-inch/6291537?seq=21) says as part of their tear-down the part number is Samsung MZ-CPA1280/0A2. This part is [available on Amazon JP](http://www.amazon.co.jp/SAMSUNG%E8%A3%BD-MacBook-%E4%BA%A4%E6%8F%9B%E7%94%A8SSD-MZ-CPA1280-0A2-%E8%BC%B8%E5%85%A5%E5%93%81/dp/B006OG1KDU) where its dimensions are specified as "Size : 24.0 × 3.9 × 108.9mm"